# Embedding a web based game into an Android Application

Tags: php, android

I've created a simple web based game (text driven) in PHP and have recently become very interested in moving this onto Android - originally i thought the game could be rewritten in Java but after some investigation i found you can embed pages straight into an Android application.

Am i missing something or will i be able to simply embed my web application into Android and expect it to work flawlessly? Is there any issues i should be aware of? My app uses a login system utilising sessions / cookies - will this pose a problem for Android users?

I'd be interested in hearing anyones thoughts that have done something similar and any issues they've encountered. The only issue i forsee is how the page renders on different phones (although this i imagine this can be somewhat nullified by good markup and well thought out javascript) and any issues in regards to sessions / cookies?

If anyone has any good resources for doing this sort of work i'd be grateful.

As a final thought it'd be good to hear peoples thoughts on whether i should rewrite it or keep it embedded, what are the benefits of rewriting it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebView` class provides access to a full fledged webkit browser. As a matter of fact, the default Android Browser itself is implemented using that very same `WebView` implementation. Javascript, Sessions and Cookies should be no problem whatsoever, you probably just have to activate them (see `WebSettings`).

Even flash should more or less work on newer devices, but I don't have any experience with that.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html for further details.

Generally, using Apps as so called "launchers", i.e. apps that basically only contain a browser window are somewhat frowned upon, since the android market isn't meant to replicate the world wide web. I do somewhat understand the need for that though, since visibility is much higher and Google does not yet provide a way to treat web apps as first class citizens, like they do for Chrome OS.

On the other hand, if your app already works fine using php, I don't see any need to rewrite it in native code.

Comment: When you say frowned about - in what sense? Will these affect whether the app is successfully submitted to the market?

Comment: No, it's just that they would prefer it if you only used native apps if you're actually leveraging their advantages, and would otherwise stick to the web. But they don't enforce that. Also, some users might perceive apps like that somewhat negatively, since they expect a more "native feel" of them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://phpforandroid.net/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Not sure it's quite what i want (please correct me if i'm wrong) as looks like that provides a library to access the lower level android functions using PHP in a scripting like fashion. I'm more looking to port my existing application to Android and wondering whether i can simply embed it or whether i should rewrite it, appreciate i could probably rewrite in phpforandroid but it'd probably require just as much work as using Java and so i don't really see the benefits (probably a seperate discussion).